# No Output fast-csv writeToPath

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am writing a script which at its core parses a .csv file for certain columns storing them in an array and then writes the contents to another .csv file. I am able to parse the file using fast-csv and have confirmed in the terminal that my array is in the correct format. However, when I attempt to write this array using the fast-csv to a .csv file, the contents never appear in the file and no errors are thrown. I have validated that the array is being passed all the way through to the callback. In addition I have gone so far as to replace that variable in the writeToPath function with a simple array  and still no luck. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
   const processFile = (fileName, file, cb) => {


    let writeData = []
    let tempArray = []

    csv.fromPath(basePath + file, {ignoreEmpty: false, headers: false})
      .on("data", function(data){
        if (data[0] != ''){
        [startDate, endDate] = fileName
        tempArray[0] = data[0]
        tempArray[1] = data[1]
        tempArray[2] = data[2]
        tempArray[3] = data[3]
        tempArray[4] = data[4]
        tempArray[5] = data[8]
        tempArray[6] = ""
        tempArray[7] = ""
        tempArray[8] = ""
        tempArray[9] = startDate
        tempArray[10] = endDate
        writeData[i] = tempArray
        writeData.shift()
        tempArray = []
        i++

        }
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log('end')
    }).on('finish', (() => {
      cb(writeData)
    }));
  }
```

```
    processFile(fileName, file, (csvData) => {
          console.log(csvData)
          csv.writeToPath('./working-files/top.csv', {headers: false}, csvData).on("finish", () => {
            console.log('done')
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, without any context to the dataset you are using, there is only so much I can suggest. The variables needed to debug this properly would be: the file, the file names used and whatever 'i' is. If you can update this then I'll be happy to take another look.

I would suggest going back and logging the variables after each step that would modify them, hopefully then you'll get a better picture as what is going wrong.

I understand this isn't a complete answer and it will probably get removed but I don't have the 50 needed reputation to make a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. basePath + path is simply a path used by the fromPath function which points to the file name. As mentioned in my original post, I have outputted the data throughout the operation including in the callback. All comes out ok. I can even take the terminal output, and paste it into another file with some simpler code using this module and it writes.

Comment: @mattymil ok, so it is literally just an issue with the .writeToPath function? If so I'd suggest filing a bug report with the package author. Have you tried writeToString? If that works you can then write it to a file afterwards

Comment: I’ll give the writeToString a try. Thanks for the input.